# Trouble executing Salesforce web service!

Tags: webservices

I have  written a web service in Salesforce, that when executed by a 3rd party, would create a Task in Salesforce.

When I am trying to execute it using Apigee (https://snap.apigee.com/1ShlySU), I am getting the following error.

```
{
    "message":"Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [line:1, column:2]",
    "errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
}
```

The service I have written is:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CreateActivity/*')
global class CreateActivity_API
{
global static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(string str)
{
    return str!=null || !String.isBlank(str); 
}

    @HttpPost
    global static Task createTask(string status, string priority) 
    {
        if(isNotNullOrEmpty(status) && isNotNullOrEmpty(priority))
        {
            Task newTask = new Task();
            newTask.whoId = '00Q28000001Pr51';
            newTask.status = 'Not Started';
            newTask.priority = 'Normal';
            newTask.subject = 'From Web';
            newTask.OwnerId = '00528000000eGrl';
            return newTask;         
       }
       else 
       {
           System.Debug('Required field values are not provided here');
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Any suggestions either in code or in the way of executing the service is appreciated.

Comment: The error is saying that the string you are posting is not valid JSON. It just needs to be of this form `{"status": "xxx", "priority": "yyy"}`. Are you missing the quotes around the field names? It's best to generate JSON using a well tried framework rather than built the string manually; that avoids syntax problems (including the handling of embedded delimiters and line feeds).

Comment: Hey @KeithC I am kinda new to this services and am exploring them. So, could you suggest me the best possible ways to write a standout one, like the one you mentioned "generate JSON using a well tried framework"

Comment: I mean something like [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) in Java or the [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) class in Apex; basically find the classes for whatever language you are using to generate and parse JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of the code. I called this rest service from WorkBench and Apigee and from both the task is created tasks successfully.

**VF Page**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping= '/CreateActivity/*')
global with sharing class CreateActivity_API {
    global static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(string str) {
        return str != null || !String.isBlank(str);
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static Task createTask(String status, String priority) {
        System.debug('status: '+status);
        System.debug('priority: '+priority);    
        if (isNotNullOrEmpty(status) && isNotNullOrEmpty(priority)) {
            Task newTask = new Task();
            newTask.whoId = '003i000001TPlOT';// Set Scheduling Contact
            newTask.status = status;
            newTask.priority = priority;
            newTask.subject = 'From Web';
            newTask.WhatId = '001i000000gDY4a';// Refer to Account Object
            try{
                insert newTask;
                return newTask;
            }catch(System.DMLException e){
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }            
        } else {
            System.Debug('Required field values are not provided here');
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Apigee screenshot:**
In Apigee, first use Salesforce as Authentication provider and pass the parameters as JSON.

[image]
[image]

**WorkBench Screenshot**

[image]

If this helps you, mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks @SarojBera this did work. I did figure out  my mistake, I was sending the "POST" parameters in a wrong manner in the body and thus was facing that issue.